# Dropping all id rows if at least one cell meets a given criterion (e.g. has a missing value)

Tags: subset, stata

My dataset is in the following form:

```
clear

input   id  var

            1   20      
            1   21      
            1   32      
            1   34     
            2   11     
            2   .     
            2   15     
            3   21     
            3   22    
            3   1     
            3   2
            3   5
end
```

In my true dataset, observations are sorted by `id` and by `year` (not shown here).

What I need to do is to drop *all* the rows of a specific `id` if (at least) one of the following two conditions is met:

1. there is at least one missing value of `var`.
2. `var` decreases from one row to the next (for the same `id`)

So in my example what I would like to obtain is:

```
       id  var

        1   20      
        1   21      
        1   32      
        1   34
```

Now, my unfortuante attempt has been to use row-wise operations together with `by`, in order to create a `drop1` variable to be later used to subset the dataset.
Something on these lines (which is clearly wrong), :

```
bysort id: gen drop1=1 if var[_n] < var[_n-1] | var[_n]==.
```

This doesn't work, and I am not even sure that I am considering the most "clean" and direct way to solve the task.

How would you proceed? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: do you really mean to drop an observation if the `var` decreases *from one observation to the next*, or do you want the results of your sample output? - those are two different requests.

Comment: yes, I really mean to drop

Comment: Ah, I see. Well certainly @Roberto's answer is superior to mine in terms of elegance and efficiency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My interpretation is that you want to drop the complete group if either of two conditions are met. I assume your dataset is sorted in some way, most likely, based on another variable. Otherwise, the structure is fragile.

The logic is simple. Check for decreasing values but leave out the first observation of each group, i.e., leave out `_n == 1`. The first observation, if non-missing, will always be smaller. Then, check also for missings.

```
clear
set more off

input   id  var
            1   20      
            1   21      
            1   32      
            1   34     
            2   11     
            2   .     
            2   15     
            3   21     
            3   22    
            3   1     
            3   2
            3   5
end

// maintain original sequencing
gen orig = _n
order id orig

bysort id (orig) : gen todrop = sum((var < var[_n-1] & _n > 1) | missing(var))
list, sepby(id)

by id : drop if todrop[_N]
list, sepby(id)
```

Comment: thanks, your interpretation is correct. A residual question: what does the final "drop if todrop[_N]" by id do? Does it drop in case the todrop variable is != 0?

Comment: The first part just marks the observations. The `sum()` function is important, because it propagates observations violating any condition, to the end. The second part checks if the last observation of `todrop`, per `id`, evaluates to _True_ (or positive). If it does, it `drop`s the complete group.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the observations violating the conditions don't propagate. _Information_ on whether an observation violates the conditions, do.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to create some indicator variable as you had attempted. If you only want to drop where `var` decreases from one observation to the next, you could use:

```
clear
input   id  var
        1   20      
        1   21      
        1   32      
        1   34     
        2   11     
        2   .     
        2   15     
        3   21     
        3   22    
        3   1     
        3   2
        3   5
        4   .
        4   2
 end

gen i = id if mi(var)
bysort id : egen k = mean(i)

drop if id == k

drop i k

drop if var[_n-1] > var[_n] & _n != 1
```

However, if you want to get the output you supplied in the post (drop all subsequent observations where `var` decreases from some max value), you could try the following in place of the last line above.

```
local N = _N

forvalues i = 1/`N' {
    drop if var[_n-1] > var[_n] & _n != 1
}
```

The loop just ensures that the `drop if var...` section of code is executed enough so that all observations where `var < 34` are dropped.